# Oracle SQL Developer Unable to Reset the Password - Reset Password dialog box is not active -ORA 28001

Tags: sql, oracle, passwords, oracle-sqldeveloper, reset

[image][image][image]I am trying to reset the password in Oracle SQL Developer. I can access the "Reset Password" option. But after that the respective dialog box is not active. I am unable to enter the inputs in that reset password dialog box. Observe the below screen shot :

[image]

Comment: Works for me. Which SQL Developer version do you use? Are you currently logged in as user whose password you want to change? If not, try to connect first, and then change the password.

Comment: What operating system are you using?  Your fonts look a bit wrong - notice how the bottom of many letters is often cut off.  I wonder if this is some weird GUI/OS bug.  If you post more information there's a good chance one of the developers of the program will respond here.

Comment: Hi All, I am using Windows 10 Operating System. Oracle SQL Developer Version 19.1 . I am unable to login into the SQL Developer itself , as it is asking for RESET PASSWORD. Also, the reset password dialog box is being popped up but its not active and I am unable to provide the inputs in that pop up box.